# how remove an interface from bridge?

Tags: linux, bridge

For some reason, we noticed two physical interfaces (`eth0`, `eth3`) are under the same bridge `vmeth0`. We need to remove `eth3` from `vmeth0` bridge without affecting the rest of the configuration. Please advise any instruction to make this possible?

We are using Linux (Redhat -release 6.8)

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
vmbondeth0              8000.0010e0cdc56b       no              bondeth0
                                                        vif90.1
vmeth0          8000.0010e0cdc56a       no              eth0
                                                        eth3
                                                        vif90.0
```

Comment: @Janka, will it only remove `eth3` from the bridge? Or will it remove the `vmeth0` as well?

Comment: Thanks that helps to remove the interface which answers my question. I believe we have configured a interface bridge name wrongly which caused this issue and we have corrected it. If we now create a new bridge ex. vmeth3 for interface eth3, we don't see the virtual interface created. Should we need to restart the server? Please post your previous answer so we can select as our answer to our question.

Comment: Done, and no, you don't have to restart the server. But you could restart the network service and see if the wrong setting reappears. (This also removes the wrong bridge configuration once you have configured the files correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
# brctl delif vmeth0 eth3
```

will remove the interface *eth3* from the bridge *vmeth0*. See the *brctl* manpage, e.g. [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/brctl) for more details.

Please note this command only affects the current bridge settings in the kernel. If you have configured your bridge wrong in the configuration files of your distribution, the wrong setting will reappear as soon you restart the network, e.g. on reboot.

For RedHat Linux, the relevant documentation about the configuration files is [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_network-bridge).

You have to restart the network service to apply those settings from the configuration files.

```
# systemctl restart network
```

should do the trick.

Comment: For current readers: this might be appropriate for RHEL 6, but actually `brctl` from `bridge-utils` is long time obsolete (this answer could only be right because RedHat 6 is ancient too). For more recent distros (RHEL 7, Debian 9 and later and so on) use the other answer, it suggests the use of `ip` utility from `iproute2` package, which is the proper way to manage modern Linux networking stack.

Answer (score 5):

As you can add an interface to a bridge by using iproute2 like:

```bash
sudo ip link set dev eth3 master vmeth0
```

You can instead set `nomaster` to make this interface not a slave interface of any bridge interface and thus remove it from the bridge like:

```bash
sudo ip link set dev eth3 nomaster
```